# How transform text areas into nicEditor by class?

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor, nicedit

I don't need transform **all** textareas on page. But I found only 1 method to transform - nicEditors.allTextAreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [examples of it](http://nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=3). You need to use [`nicEditor.panelInstance`](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/521/Javascript%20API).

```
var options = { ... };
var editor = new nicEditor(options).panelInstance('textareaID');
```

Yet this works also with an element's ID. But, you can dynamically generate a random ID for your desired element and fetch it to `nicEditor.panelInstance`.

Comment: so is the answer to the question a "No, you can not target elements and make them into editors by targeting the classname. You have to generate a random id and still use id" ?